# Выдает OOPS! THAT PAGE CAN’T BE FOUND WordPress 4.8

Tags: wordpress

Установил WAMP server64 на Windows 10. Скачал  WordPress (Version 4.8) с wordpress.org/download/ Создал базу данных. Создал пользователя.

Установил WordPress 4.8, набрал в браузере http://localhost/wordpress/. И сайт запустился.

Теперь я хочу сделать копию этого сайта, скопировать файлы в другую папку, создать другую базу, импортировать таблицы. Сделал. В wp-конфиг:

```
define('DB_NAME', 'new_word');
```

Изменил название базы на другую. http://localhost/new_word/.

Выдает OOPS! THAT PAGE CAN’T BE FOUND. Что еще нужно менять и где, чтобы запустился сайт?

Answer (score 1):

Менять надо все. WordPress жестко прописывает ссылки по сайту внутри базы, поэтому копирование папок не поможет.

Самый простой способ - повторить установку нового сайта, и не в подпапке, а в другой, параллельной папке. И создать новую базу, само собой.

Для переноса готовых сайтов на WordPress есть специальные плагины, например, [Duplicator](https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/).

Comment: А когда с локалки   заливается на хостинг. 

То как ?  

Копируешь файлы но хостинг  
по ФТП, в и загружаешь базу (SQL) ? 

Как тогда ?

Comment: @VitalieBancu Тем же дубликатором.

Answer (score 1):

В локальном сервере стоит создать [вилуталхосты](https://ru.wikibooks.org/wiki/VirtualHost) ([virtualhost](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html)) и работать с сайтами как с отдельными доменами, а не в подкаталогах localhost.

Для каждого сайта создавать свою базу.

Для клонирования сайта использовать плагины для миграции. Напр https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/

Answer (score 0):

В общем у меня проблема решается банальным переключением между темами. Сначала, активирую любую тему из тех что есть, потом переключаюсь обратно и все в порядке.

Comment: Уточните пожалуйста, как ваше сообщение отвечает на вопрос ТС?